# saving a NSMutableDictionary to the documents directory

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary, nsdocumentdirectory

I want to save an NSMutableDictionary to the documents directory automatically when the user exits a view. Here is the code I am trying to implement.  It isn't working though.  Can someone help me out.

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                                       @"audio.caf",@"pictureAudioKey",
                                       @"audio.m4a",@"englishAudioKey",
                                       @"audio2.m4a",@"spanishAudioKey",
                                       @"audio3.m4a",@"frenchAudioKey",
                                       @"audio4.m4a",@"germanAudioKey",
                                       @"audio5.m4a",@"italianAudioKey",
                                       @"audio6.m4a",@"chineseAudioKey",
                                       @"image.jpg",@"photoimagekey",
                                       @"name.txt", @"identity", 
                                       @"imagename.txt",@"numberkey",nil];

    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dictionaryPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[self imageNameTextField]text]];
    dictionaryPath =[dictionaryPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"dicitonary" ] ;
    NSDictionary *savedDictionary = dictionary;


    NSLog(@"The Save file is:%@", savedDictionary);

    [savedDictionary writeToFile:dictionaryPath atomically:YES];

       [super viewDidUnload];

}
```

---

So I got the dictionary to save to the documents directory by putting it with a button.
Like this

```
- (void)saveAction:(id)sender {



    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                                       @"audio.caf",@"pictureAudioKey",
                                       @"image.jpg",@"photoimagekey",
                                       @"name.txt", @"identity", 
                                       @"imagename.txt",@"numberkey",nil];



    NSArray *documentPaths3 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectory3 = [documentPaths3 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dictionaryPath3 = [documentsDirectory3 stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[self imageNameTextField]text]];
    dictionaryPath3 =[dictionaryPath3 stringByAppendingFormat:@"dictionary" ] ;
    NSDictionary *savedDictionary2 = dictionary;


    NSLog(@"The Save file is:%@", savedDictionary2);

    [savedDictionary2 writeToFile:dictionaryPath3 atomically:YES];
```

when I look in my documents directory it has a file named 1dictionary 
when I open it with text exit it looks like this

```
<key>identity</key>
<string>name.txt</string>
<key>numberkey</key>
<string>imagename.txt</string>
<key>photoimagekey</key>
<string>image.jpg</string>
<key>pictureAudioKey</key>
<string>audio.caf</string>
```

I am now trying to load the dictionary in an if statement like this.

```
if ((int)index == 0) {

      FinalDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[FinalDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FinalDetailViewController" bundle:nil];


        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,   
                                                             NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        //Get a full path to the image in the documents directory.
        NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1dictionary"];

        NSDictionary *myDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
        NSMutableDictionary *familyDictionary =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:myDictionary];
        /*NSMutableDictionary *familyDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                 @"audio.caf",@"pictureAudioKey",
                                                 @"image.jpg",@"photoimagekey",
                                                 @"name.txt", @"identity", 
                                                 @"imagename.txt",@"numberkey",nil];*/

        detailViewController.familyDictionary = familyDictionary;

         [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    }
```

but it doesn't go app crashes with

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "it isn't working"?  What happens when you run your code?

Comment: I doesn't show up in the documents directory

Comment: (Have you noticed you spelled the filename wrong? Are you looking in the dir for the wrong file?)

Comment: Thanks for seeing that but that is not the issue.  I am looking in the simulator's documents file on my computer.  I can see other things that are saved there but not this file.  I want the dictionary to be saved as (whatever the user inputs into a textfield) followed by the word dictionary.  And it is not there.  Is This possible?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are referencing the textfield text in viewDidUnload. At this point, the view and its subviews are gone. You should try this code in -viewWillDisappear:

Comment: I tried it in viewWillDisappear with no luck.  Can I put strings referencing Audio files, image files, and text files in this and also can I reference objects which don't exist in the documents directory but in the main Bundle?

Comment: I finally gave up and just had it saved when a button was tapped. Works fine now.  Thx 4 all the help

Answer (score 0):

You assemble the file path differently in the save and load method. I think you are missing a [dictionaryPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"dictionary"] from the load file path. Then the exception is thrown at `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];`